# Installing modules through pip in a virtualenv in an AWS Lambda function - no error message

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, pip, virtualenv

I'm trying to start a Lambda server that starts other Lambda servers. To do that, I need to install the modules required for each server in the deployment server. This is difficult because the Lambda server is extremely bare, it doesn't come with pip, virtualenv, or sudo and it gives few permissions. So far I've successfully uploaded a virtualenv directory and have called its pip with subprocess.check_output to install modules. However, some (particularly pandas, numpy, and psycopg2 so far) modules simply refuse to install, quitting with exit status 1 and no other information. Here's an example of a successful, then unsuccessful install:

```
Installing module: requests
The directory '/home/sbx_user1051/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/sbx_user1051/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting requests
  Downloading requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (501kB)
Installing collected packages: requests
Successfully installed requests-2.9.1
You are using pip version 8.0.0, however version 8.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Installing module: numpy
Command '['/tmp/lambdaTools/venv/bin/pip install numpy']' returned non-zero exit status 1: CalledProcessError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambdaTools.py", line 39, in lambdaTools_handler
    return operations[operation](event)
  File "/var/task/lambdaTools.py", line 31, in <lambda>
    x.get('python_project'),
  File "/var/task/lambdaTools.py", line 83, in createFunction
    print(subprocess.check_output([local_path+'venv/bin/pip install '+module],shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
CalledProcessError: Command '['/tmp/lambdaTools/venv/bin/pip install numpy']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

This comes from the code

```
print(subprocess.check_output(['python',local_path+'virtualenv-14.0.0/virtualenv.py',local_path+'venv']))

for module in module_list:
     print('Installing module:',module)
     print(subprocess.check_output([local_path+'venv/bin/pip install '+module],shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT))
```

So two things:

Can anyone help me figure out why requests installs but numpy fails?
If not, can I find a way to produce a more useful error message?
Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how you're activating the virtualenv. Do you need to force pip to install into your virtualenv tree with -t /path/to/project-dir?

Comment: I was able to just use `path/to/virtualenv/bin/pip install requests`. I'll update the question with the code I use to set up virtualenv.

Comment: May be related to the numpy package requiring C compilation while the requests package is native Python.